# Select region between two rows. Many lines

Tags: text

Emacs 27.1

Suppose I has text file with 50_000 rows.

I want to select region from row number 10_000 to row number 30_000.

How I can do this in Emacs?

Comment: You were given the answer in a comment to your previous question: search for the beginning line, set a mark, search for the ending line, and narrow.  Or go to the beginning line number, set a mark, go to the ending line number and narrow. These are *very elementary* operations that you should know about by now: you've been around for many years.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show text between two lines](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/80690/show-text-between-two-lines)

Comment: The command `M-x goto-line`, bound to `M-g g` by default, will allow you to jump to the 10,000th row and 30,000th row. Otherwise the answer from your previous question applies here.